# Error: conflicting types for ‘strlen’

Tags: c

I have a program, but I get an error message. Please help me on this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int print_strlen(char s[]);

main()
{
    char s[20];
    printf("Enter the string:\n");
    scanf("%s\n", s);
}

int print_strlen(char s[])
{
    int l;
    l = strlen(s);
    printf("Length of the string is: %s\n", l);
}
```

Comment: And the error message being...? EDIT: Never mind.. it was in the subject line. Do you really think people want to help you out when you start the subject line with "Solve this"?

Comment: `scanf("%19s", s);`

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to prototype `strlen` yourself. Just include `<string.h>`, and use the prototype (and function) it already has. Don't try to write a function of your own with the same name (or, at least officially, any other name starting with `str`).

The conflicting type it's seeing right now is because the standard requires `strlen` to return a `size_t`, not an `int`.

Also note that the function you have named `strlen` right now is infinitely recursive -- where it (apparently) tries to call the standard `strlen`, it'll end up calling itself, and since it does that unconditionally, it'll keep recursing forever (or until the system kills it for overflowing the stack, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

strlen is already defined in string.h hence the error. Change your function name to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Call your function something else, there is already a `strlen()` declared in `string.h`.

Answer (score 0):

strlen is a standard function declared in `<string.h>` and you are trying to define it with another prototype (the standard function takes a `char const*`, not a `char*`).

Answer (score 0):

What is your error message?

You shouldn't name your function `strlen`; there is already a `strlen` function and you know that won't work because you use the real `strlen` function in your `strlen` function. Call it something else, like `print_strlen`. Also, use `void` instead of `int` if you're not actually returning anything from `print_strlen`.

Other problems not directly related include the obvious buffer overflow; what if you entered text more than 20 bytes long?

Answer (score 0):

strlen is a function provided for you in string.h why reinvent the wheel?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
        char s[20];
        printf("Enter the string:\n");
        scanf("%s\n",s);
        printf("Length of the string is: %s\n",strlen(s));
}
```

would work perfectly fine.

Comment: i know. but i'm trying to implement it in recursive form. so pls modify my program from errors

Comment: There is nothing recursive about your program. If you are struggling with recursion, please ask a new question, with proper explanation of that problem, not this one which was an error.

Comment: "Perfectly fine", except for the "%s" in the format string (copied from the question).